# How to I make a Magento module that can CRUD a custom table, inside the admin panel?

Tags: magento

I've been following a tutorial, but it doesn't work on the latest version Magento 1.7, and nobody here could help me with it :( so I've decided to ask a new question from scratch with no code in it.

I already know how to make Magento modules (to some extent), as I made a working one for the frontend, but I'll need one for the backend admin panel, where I can create, edit and delete a custom table inside the database.

From hereonwards, assume that I have configured config.xml and got a blank admin page to load, (or you could not), but it would be easier to just say I just have a blank admin page, and I need the rest of the code to fill out the content and empty logic.

Comment: To CRUD a table you need to setup a proper model and/or resource. It doesn't matter, whether you want to use that model in the frontend or the backend, the setup is the same. Maybe [Part 5 - Magento Model and ORM Basics](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) and [Part 6 - Magento Setup Resources](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources) of Alan Storm's Magento for Developers Series are of help here.

Comment: I have a model and resource setup. I have all the relevant model files created for my table along with a setup script, with also the config.xml setup correctly so that the module works with the database. Now what I need now, is the code to allow me to edit the entries in this table, using the admin panel, in a custom module. I have the empty page setup as an admin module page that came as a custom menu entry, too. :)

Comment: Same rendering engine works for both frontend and adminhtml. Which tutorial were you following?

Comment: I've used three. They all work the same. It doesn't matter. I have my config.xml setup. Look. https://gist.github.com/0c276136c96e9d353ef0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best example of a complete CRUD implementation including setup script to create the table, model classes, and a complete admin form to view/edit/delete and export the records is that provided by moduleCreator.  moduleCreator will create your module for you then populate it with the complete back end and front end (if required).  You can get moduleCreator from [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html) or an updated version from [GitHub](https://github.com/shell/Magento-Module-Creator).

Comment: I think I've found the applicable code here. https://github.com/shell/Magento-Module-Creator/tree/master/blank/app/code/local/Namespace/Moduleadmin

Comment: That's the template code that module creator uses when it creates the module.  That will give you a complete example to work from without having to use moduleCreator to create a complete module.

Comment: That's nice and all, but I was kind of hoping for something done from scratch, tutorial based.